# AS3 bitmapData.Draw is very inefficient

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, air, bitmap

I am using ActionScript 3 in Flash CS6 with Adobe AIR 3.4

I am trying to load an image from the file system into a Bitmap.

My current code is:

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("assets\\" + filename));

private function loadComplete(e:Event):void
{
    //add to bitmap
    bitmap = new Bitmap();
    bitmap.bitmapData = new BitmapData(loader.width, loader.height, true, 0x000000);

    bitmap.bitmapData.draw(loader);
}
```

However there is very inefficient performance at bitmapData.draw (the image is 2048x1536).
I have tried:

```
bitmap.bitmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData;
```

However it does not affect the performance. And is still very slow.

How can I load the image in the loader into a Bitmap without having such slow performance.

Comment: Using drawWithQuality and using StageQuality.LOW does nothing to increase performance

Comment: Is the draw slow or the loading of the file slow ? Have you distinguished the time between those two processes ? Also, slow is rather vague, expressing the delay in real time units like seconds or milliseconds would be helpful.

Comment: The draw is slow, the loading is very quick.

I do not know the exact time that it takes to draw but it is 1-2 seconds (which is not okay because I am programming a game)

Comment: How did you distinguish between the draw and the load times ? How often are you loading/drawing this bitmap ?

Comment: I commented out the draw code and there was no waiting  time

Comment: It's a large bitmap at 2048x1536, which is why I ask how many times you need to draw it to a bitmapData. It's common to do pre-rendering and things of that nature before starting a game. If it's a spritesheet, it only needs to be done once before the game starts.

Comment: I probably am rendering too many times. And yes it is a spritesheet

Comment: I made the game load the spritesheet at the beginning (once) and reference it every time it needed to be used. Now the game runs without any delay

Answer (score 3):

When you load an image with a `Loader`, you already get a `Bitmap`. So why do you `draw()` into another one?

Just do this:

```
private function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    bitmap = loader.contentLoaderInfo.content as Bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I wish it was as simple as that, but it does not fix the performance issue.

Comment: You comment on your original question that if you don't `draw()` there's no delay. Are you still drawing the bitmap into another one? If you really need to do something like that, check out `copyPixels` (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29)

Comment: There is very slight delay (because I am calling `copyPixels` 48 times after this code executes. I am working with a spritesheet where first I load the Loader, put it in a bitmap (the problem in this question) and then copy the 48 individual images to an array.

Comment: But you should just skip the step of putting the loaded image in a Bitmap because **it is a Bitmap already**.